# How did Maxwell draw his figure showing the path of molecules repelling with a force proportional to the inverse of the fifth power of the distance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, history, approximations

Maxwell has this figure in his paper [*On the dynamical theory of gases*](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstl.1867.0004) (page 61):
[image]

This is the description of the figure:

> The paths described by molecules about a centre of force S, repelling
> inversely as the fifth power of the distance, are given in the figure.
>
> The molecules are supposed to be originally moving with equal
> velocities in parallel paths, and the way in which their deflections
> depend on the distance of the path from S is shown by the different
> curves in the figure.

I would like to reproduce the figure and I have some questions about it, I am aware that full correct answers are nearly impossible (I cannot ask to Maxwell since he is dead and it seems to me highly improbable he wrote a *Supplemental Material* section where he detailed how he drew the figure) but maybe some historians of science can help.

1. Is the horizontal scale of the figure the same as the vertical one? Or, put in another words, is there any physical reason to employ here a *vertical exaggeration* different from one?
2. What does the black line above $S$ mean? Why is it partially dashed and partially solid?
3. How did he actually draw the figure? Did he compute some points on the trajectories, drew them and then interpolate by free hand in-between?

For the first question I think that the radial symmetry of the problem calls for equal vertical and horizontal scale.

For the third question, maybe there is some smart trick to compute the oblique asymptotes?

My first attempts in replication give this figure but I am not happy with:

[image]

You can see they do not overlap well:

[image]

Comment: Seems pretty close to me. Some slight variances that is all. What is the issue?